# C# XML Serialization: Assign the same value multiple times

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, enums

I'm using enum flags in a project I'm working on and a lot of XML serialization. I'd like to be able to assign multiple different enum flags to a single enum parameter. The problem I'm running into is that values will only be assigned once, while I want to be able to assign multiple enums.

I have a working solution using strings and an array:

```
[XmlElement("AddTags")]
public string[] AddTags
{
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
            foreach (string tag in value)
            {
                if (tag.Contains(","))
                {
                    string[] split = tag.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    foreach (string str in split)
                        Tags = (Tags | (int)EnumUtil.GetIndex<Tag>(str));
                }
                else
                    Tags = (Tags | (int)EnumUtil.GetIndex<Tag>(tag));
            }
    }
    get
    {
        return EnumUtil.GetNamesInTag<Tag>(Tags).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Which gives me the desired result, except I'd much prefer to just used a serialied enum. The XML for this would look like:

```
<AddTags>Tag1</AddTags>
<AddTags>Tag2</AddTags>
```

And all be set to a single int containing each of these enum flags.

Ideally this would work with the same XML:

```
[Flags]
public enum Tag
{
    Tag1     = 1 << 00,
    Tag2     = 1 << 01,
    Tag3     = 1 << 02,
}
public int Tags;
public Tag AddTags
{
    set
    {
        Tags = (Tags | (int)value);
    }
    get
    {
        return (Tag)Tags;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the xml will only assign AddTags once regardless of how many times because AddTags is no longer an Array. I would like be able to assign this value multiple times, using the same xml, and without creating an array as I feel like that's over complication. Thanks.

Comment: I love the idea of this, but: I don't think that `XmlSerializer` is going to support it, unless you basically spoof a custom list (which would be inefficient, especially at serialize time)

Comment: You interface should be a string : public string AddTags  Then convert from enum to string is .ToString() and to go from string to enum you can use (Tag)Enum.Parse(Tag, "Tag1")